# "Well-parallelized" algorithm not sped up by multiple threads

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm sorry to ask a question one a topic that I know so little about, but this idea has really been bugging me and I haven't been able to find any answers on the internet.

**Background:**
I was talking to one of my friends who is in computer science research. I'm in mostly ad-hoc development, so my understanding of a majority of CS concepts is at a functional level (I know how to use them rather than how they work). He was saying that converting a "well-parallelized" algorithm that had been running on a single thread into one that ran on multiple threads didn't result in the processing speed increase that he was expecting.

**Reasoning:**
I asked him what the architecture of the computer he was running this algorithm on was, and he said 16-core (non-virtualized). According to what I know about multi-core processors, the processing speed increase of an algorithm running on multiple cores should be roughly proportional to how well it is parallelized.

**Question:**
How can an algorithm that is "well-parallelized" and programmed correctly to run on a true multi-core processor not run several times more quickly? Is there some information that I'm missing here, or is it more likely a problem with the implementation?

**Other stuff:** I asked if the threads were possibly taking up more power than any individual core had available and apparently each core runs at 3.4 GHz. This is much more than the algorithm should need, and when diagnostics are run the cores aren't maxed out during runtime.

Comment: Get your friend who wrote the code and has the computer to post the details of this particular instance. The general answer to your question "Why does random parallel code not speed up?" fills several textbooks and research conferences.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely sharing *something*. What is being shared may not be obvious.

One of the most common non-obvious shared resources is CPU cache. If the threads are updating the same cache line that cache line has to bounce between CPUs, slowing everything down.

That can happen because of accessing (even read-only) variables which are near to each other in memory. If all accesses are read-only it is OK, but if even one CPU is writing to that cache line it will force a bounce.

A brute-force method of fixing this is to put shared variables into structures that look like:

```
struct var_struct {
    int value;
    char padding[128];
};
```

Instead of hard-coding 128 you could research what system parameter or preprocessor macros define the cache-line size for your system type.

Another place that sharing can take place is inside system calls. Even seemingly innocent functions might be taking global locks. I seem to recall reading about Linux fixing an issue like this a while back with locks on the functions that return process and thread identifiers and parent identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, I was talking to another researcher and he said something similar to this... I'll try and see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Performance versus number of cores is often a S-like curve - first it obviously increases but as locking, shared cache and the like take they debt the further cores do not add so much and even may degrade. Hence nothing mysterious. If we would know more details about the algorithm it may be possible to find an idea to speed it up.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you're saying a little more? I understand that what you're saying would be true for a non- or poorly- parallelized algorithm, but not necessarily in the case I describe. The performance only increased very minutely when run across multiple cores, so it doesn't appear to even be following an S-curve.